can we apply Lebesgue’s Dominated Convergence Theorem to prove continuity

Examine the continuity of the function $$F(a) =
 \int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{xdx}{2+x^{a}}, \quad a > 2$$

I'm trying to apply Lebesgue’s Dominated Convergence Theorem
Let pick $a_0 >2$ and a sequence $(a_n)$ s.t $a_n\to a_0$ as $n\to\infty$. I wish to prove $F(a_n)\to F(a_0)$. From that, I can conclude $F$ is continuous on $(2,\infty)$.
But I can't choose a suitable dominating function $g$ to apply Lebesgue’s Dominated Convergence Theorem.
Could someone help me or have a better way to deal with the problem? Thanks in advance!

If $\epsilon>0$ is small enough that for all large $n$, we have $a_n\geq a_0-\epsilon>2$ then using this exponent will work (perhaps with some fiddling of prefactors).

$g(x)=\frac 1  21_{0<x<1}+\frac  1{x^{a-1}} 1_{x\ge 1}$ is a dominating integrable function.

@geetha290krm could you be more specific about how you apply this theorem to solve this problem in the answering section down below so that I can understand better? If yes, I would be very appreciative
